# filter data between a date range MongoDB with C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, mongodb, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

Hi I am working on a function where I have to get the data in a file according to the ID and the Start and End date.

This is what I wrote so far.

*In controller*

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("searchLogs")]
public async Task<ActionResult> SearchLogs([FromBody] List<Logs> logs)
{
    var response = await logProvider.SearchLogs(logs);
    return Ok(response);
}
```

*In model class*

```
public class Logs
{
    public DateTime Date{get; set;}
    public string Id {get; set;}
}
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: where is your mongodb part?

Answer (score 3):

`db` is type of `IMongoDbContext`

`startDate` and `endDate` is `DateTime`

```
 var q =  db.GetCollection<Logs>().Find(x => x.Date >= startDate.Date &&  x.Date <= endDate.date).ToList();
```